# Query Foreign Table in Stream Supabase

Tags: flutter, supabase

Does anyone know how to perform a stream query to fetch some data from another table?
Something like that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck9eN.png)

I have this

```
_supabase
    .from('$table:fk_ventas=eq.$fkSales')
    .stream(['id'])
    .execute()
    .map((maps) =>
        maps.map((map) => SalesDataProduct.fromMap(map)).toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't. Stream works only with one table.

You need to figure out another way to fetch data from another table. It can be just an extra query.